# javascript change toggle button text

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of code which i use for language toggling:

```
function toggleDiv(divid) {  
varon = divid + 'on';
varoff = divid + 'off';
      if(document.getElementById(varon).style.display == 'block'){
      document.getElementById(varon).style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById(varoff).style.display = 'block';
      }
        else {  
            document.getElementById(varoff).style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById(varon).style.display = 'block'
        }
}
```

and HTML:

```
<div id="mydivon" style="display:block">some language text</div>
<div id="mydivoff" style="display:none">some other language text</div>
 <a href="#" onmousedown="toggleDiv('mydiv');">Language1/Language2</a>
```

and i would like to make toggle button switchable, when one Language1 is selected, switch toggle text to Language2 and vice versa. Some pointers would be welcome. Thx

Comment: Your code seems to work, what is the issue you're experiencing? As a note, you can cache the nodes inside the varon/varoff, so you don't have to get the same element 3 times. Edit: you can change the links text by selecting it and setting textContent to either language one or two.

Comment: Yeah, it works, but toggle button (toggle text) always stays the same, i cant make that button to change value based on selected language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described by the OP in the comments:

Currently you're displaying an element on wether it's selected but the toggle itself isn't changing language.

Now what you can do is when you mousedown and execute `toggleDiv(divid)`
there should be a special variable to your disposal called `this`

`this` basically means "this called me" in the most simple form.
In your case `this` is the `<a href="#">Language1/Language2</a>` link

So what you could do then within your function:

```
function toggleDiv(divId) {
    //also highly recommend you cache your variables
    varon = document.getElementById(divId + 'on');
    varoff = document.getElementById(divId + 'off');

    if (varon.style.display == 'block') {
        varon.style.display == 'none';
        varoff.style.display = 'block';
        this.innerHTML = varoff.innerHTML; // <- selected element value injected in bound button
    } else
        varon.style.display == 'block';
        varoff.style.display = 'none';
        this.innerHTML = varon.innerHTML; // <- selected element value injected in bound button
}
```

With the line `this.innerHTML = varon/off.innerHTML` you're saying, "the element that called me has to have the value of the block element"

The value will still default be `Language1/Language2` but as soon as you change it it will update.

Hope it helps!

**NOTE: UNTESTED**

Answer (score 2):

I've setup a **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sxzv0zdr/1/)** , is this the effect you wanted to achieve? As @Shilly already said in the comments, you can use [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) to change the content of your anchor tag.

I've assigned an ID to your anchor `#languageSwitch` so I can do following stuff in your JS

**HTML**

```
<div id="mydivon" style="display:block">
    Language 1 is selected
</div>
<div id="mydivoff" style="display:none">
    Language 2 is selected
</div>
<a id="languageSwitch" href="#" onmousedown="toggleDiv('mydiv');">
    Switch to Language2
</a>
```

**JS**

```
function toggleDiv(divid) {
    varon = divid + 'on';
    varoff = divid + 'off';
    // Assign the switch anchor to a variable
    var switcher = document.getElementById('languageSwitch');
    if (document.getElementById(varon).style.display == 'block') {
        document.getElementById(varon).style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById(varoff).style.display = 'block';
        //Change the text to language1 (language 2 is active)
        switcher.textContent = "Switch to Language1";
    } else {
        document.getElementById(varoff).style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById(varon).style.display = 'block'
        //Change the text to language2 (language 1 is active)
        switcher.textContent = "Switch to Language2";
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot about `textContent!` - not going to remove my answer, upvoted your instead ;)

Comment: I was so close, i forgot to add id to `a href` - that solved it. Thank you.

Comment: Is it supposed to work well on mobile ? Because I used your work on my portfolio and it works really nice on desktop, but on mobile it just reloads the page.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Add an id to your link:

```
<a id="toggle-language" href="#" onmousedown="toggleDiv('mydiv');">Language1/Language2</a>
```

Step 2: Change your function to:

```
function toggleDiv(divid) {  
    var on = document.getElementById(divid + 'on'),
        off = document.getElementById(divid + 'off'),
        language = document.getElementById('toggle-language');
    if (on.style.display == 'block'){
        on.style.display = 'none';
        off.style.display = 'block';
        language.textContent = 'Language 2';
    }
    else {  
        on.style.display = 'block';
        off.style.display = 'none';
        language.textContent = 'Language 1';
    }
}
```