# Changing the text back and forth using a button with pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, button

I already made the button's text change into "RETURN" whenever I first click on it, and the text inside the p tags changes from "ABC" to "Lorem ipsum". Is there any way that I can change the text back to "ABC" from "Lorem ipsum" using the "RETURN" button with JavaScript only?. Here's my code

```js
var text = document.getElementById("info");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  text.innerHTML = "Lorem ipsum";
  btn.innerHTML = "RETURN";
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p id="info">ABC</p>
<button id="btn">CLICK FOR MORE</button>
```

Comment: It is better to save the button state in a variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript change toggle button text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32314709/javascript-change-toggle-button-text)

Answer (score 2):

You can try following

```js
var text = document.getElementById("info");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
      if(btn.innerHTML === "CLICK FOR MORE") { 
         text.innerHTML = "Lorem ipsum";
         btn.innerHTML = "RETURN";
      } else {
          text.innerHTML = "ABC";
         btn.innerHTML = "CLICK FOR MORE";
      }
    });
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p id="info">ABC</p>
<button id="btn">CLICK FOR MORE</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should create a `toggle()` to change the text;

```js
var text = document.getElementById("info");
       var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
        btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
          text.innerHTML = "Lorem ipsum";
          btn.innerHTML = "RETURN";
          Toggle();
        });
        
        function Toggle() {
           if(btn.innerHTML === "Lorem ipsum") { 
     text.innerHTML = "Lorem ipsum";
     btn.innerHTML = "RETURN";
  } else {
      text.innerHTML = "RETURN";
     btn.innerHTML = "Lorem ipsum";
  }
        }
```

```html
<p id="info">ABC</p>
<button id="btn">CLICK FOR MORE</button>
```

Comment: Your answer requires some improvement. Firstly, you should not set innerHTML in click handler and should set only in toggle. Secondly, you should set the text of button and p accurately.

Comment: i am just copy and paste from w3school :) . thanks for poining out . i am fixing

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. You can set a variable outside to filp the values.

```
var text = document.getElementById("info");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var flipper = true;
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    text.innerHTML = flipper ? "Lorem ipsum" : "Prev text";
    flipper = !flipper;
    btn.innerHTML = "RETURN";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may store the original text with variables:

```js
var text = document.getElementById("info");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
let formerText = "Lorem ipsum";
let formerBtn = "RETURN";
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const tmpText = text.innerHTML;
  const tmpBtn = btn.innerHTML;
  text.innerHTML = formerText;
  btn.innerHTML = formerBtn;
  formerText = tmpText;
  formerBtn = tmpBtn;
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p id="info">ABC</p>
<button id="btn">CLICK FOR MORE</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

when you want to change test from ABC" to "Lorem ipsum" and "Lorem ipsum" to ABC respectively,i mean is it something related to odd or even click or you want if  button is clicked , text is "ABC" then change it to "Lorem ipsum" and vice-versa